# I just installed Codeigniter on (running) MAMP.. why cant I hit the welcome page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have just downloaded and unpacked Codeigniter 2.1 and put its contents into a folder called CI in my htdocs MAMP folder.  I then opened config.php and set `$config['base_url']`  to  'http://localhost:8888/CI/' as per the installation instructions.

I should now be able to navigate to localhost:8888/CI/ and hit a welcome page, correct?

All I'm getting is a 500 error.

> "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request."

MAMP is running.  So what could be my problem?

Comment: The url is localhost:8888/CI/

Comment: Thanks ..I wish that solved it. Unfortunately I had a typo in my original post (now edited).  I *AM* navigating to localhost:8888/CI/.  

Still not hitting the welcome page though.

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled? If not try enable it.

Comment: Is there anything in the MAMP error logs? I belive are located in the /Applications/MAMP/Library/logs folder

Comment: A few questions: what do you see when you go to http://localhost:8888/ and http://localhost:8888/CI/index.php/ ?

Comment: That helped.  I had tried an install previously, but it went bad and I gave up and restarted.  Unfortunately, I left the old (invisible) .htaccess file in the CI folder and it was giving me problems.

Tack så mycket!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have mod_rewrite enabled? If not you should try to enable it. And also make sure you don't have some hidden (.htaccess) file/s in the folder you try to install/unpack the framework (files) in.